# New to Python and recursion - XML parsing

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, xml-parsing

I can open and read an XML file.

What I'd like to do is a recursion to print out all child elements of the current node.

The (awful) iterative approach has nested for loops:

```py
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print (child.tag, child.text)
    for gen1 in child:
        print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t\t", gen1.text)
        for gen2 in gen1:
            print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" ,gen2.tag, "\t\t", gen2.text)
            for gen3 in gen2:
                print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" , gen2.tag, "\t", gen3.tag, "\t\t", gen3.text)
                for gen4 in gen3:
                    print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" , gen2.tag, "\t", gen3.tag, "\t", gen4.tag, "\t\t", gen4.text)
                    for gen5 in gen4:
                        print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" , gen2.tag, "\t", gen3.tag, "\t", gen4.tag, "\t", gen5.tag, "\t\t", gen5.text)
                        for gen6 in gen5:
                            print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" , gen2.tag, "\t", gen3.tag, "\t", gen4.tag, "\t", gen5.tag, "\t", gen6.tag, "\t\t", gen6.text)
                            for gen7 in gen6:
                                print(child.tag, "\t" , gen1.tag, "\t" , gen2.tag, "\t", gen3.tag, "\t", gen4.tag, "\t", gen5.tag, "\t", gen6.tag, "\t", gen7.tag, "\t\t", gen7.text)
```

I can't wrap my head around "this node has no children" for the stop of recursion. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, I might get the formatting wrong:

```
def traverse(node,ances):
    to_print = f"{ances}{node.tag}\t{node.text}"
    print(to_print)
    for child in node:
        traverse(child,to_print+"\t")

traverse(root,"")
```

You don't need to set explicit stop condition when there isn't any child. Here, there won't be any `traverse` call inside `for` loop in that case, and recursion will automatically stop.